# Erro ao editar um Objeto(activity) no Rails_Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Eu entro no rails_admin e ele funciona normalmente com os usuários, porém quando eu vou editar uma atividade ele dá esse erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já pesquisei o que poode ser, mas não achei nada muito claro. Logo Abaixo vou colocar meu model de activity pra ajudar no entendimento, e qualqer coisa so avisar que eu edito ou compartilho mais algum arquivo específico para melhor entendimento.

**MODEL**

`class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  before_update :impedir_duplicata
  after_update :validar_hora
  after_update :deletar_anexo
  before_destroy :retirar_hora
  before_destroy :deletar_anexo
  mount_uploaders :documents, DocumentUploader
  validates :hora_computada, :titulo, :grupo, :data_evento,
  :local_realizacao_atividade, :relatorio, presence: true`

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive um problema parecido, mas descobri que era por conta do Devise, e não estava autenticando. Pode ser um problema de permissão, como pode ser uma configuração. Se puder, poste como está o Config do seu rails_admin.rb, e também o Traceback (as linhas de erros) completas, que o pessoal consegue analisar melhor.

Uma ideia é escolher os campos que vão aparecer para editar no DSL do RailsAdmin. Por exemplo:

```
config.model 'Activity' do
   edit do
      field :name
      field :user
   end
end
```

E lembre-se que alguns campos são obrigatórios (not nil), e também precisam estar na lista dos fields.